# Is there any way to reduce the timeout when accessing a network resource in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, timeout

I have an app that needs to regularly (1 sec) read a file across the network.  Occasionally, the network fails me, and the app can't read the file.  Problem is, the app hangs for a very long time each time this occurs, meaning it becomes unusable.

It's actually not important if this read fails occasionally.  How can I reduce the timeout when I read from the file?  The file is read using a Delphi 2006 FileStream.  The target hardware is Win XP and 7.

Comment: You have two basic choices: You can read from the file in a thread or you can use overlapped I/O.

Comment: Thanks @David.  In this application it would be preferable to timeout after 1 sec (say) and move on and let the application continue with other more important things, hence my wanting to know about reducing the timeout.  I gather if I used overlapped I/O I could continue as soon as I had started the read, but do you know if it is possible to get at the internals  of Delphi file I/O at that level - or would I do it myself with WinAPI stuff?